# Cordless drill battery replacement

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

Can three 18650 cells connected in series be used to power a 12v cordless drill?

Comment: Anything is possible given the right sort of interface circuit. For how long will something work depends on many factors.

Comment: Yes. but performance depends on specs for cell matching & worst case capacity (mAh)

Answer (score 2):

> Can three 18650 cells connected in series be used to power a 12v cordless drill?

If they are the incorrect type, like high-capacity low-current cells used in laptops, and if there is no overcurrent protection, they will explode.

If they are the correct type, ie high-current cells, and there is no undervoltage protection, it will work for one charge and the cells will be dead due to over-discharge.

Basically it has to be done right, ie a proper battery pack with BMS including all safety features, proper balancing charger, etc.

By then it's cheaper to buy a low cost LiIon drill.